# If $a_{ij}$ typically refers to row i and j column of a matrix, then why does the notation for interchanging rows refer to j as a row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am confused by the notations I am seeing in my linear algebra class.

[Here](https://openstax.org/books/precalculus/pages/9-6-solving-systems-with-gaussian-elimination) is the book I am using and page I am on.

$R_i \leftrightarrow  R_j$ means to interchange rows $i$ and $j$ of a matrix.
But does $R_{ij}$ not mean matrix $R$, and that $i$ is the row, and $j$ is the column?

So why do we then refer to $i$ and $j$ in $R_i$ and $R_j$ both as rows now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$i$ and $j$ are just indices. They don't have any particular meaning on their own. If $R_{ij}$ is used to denote the entry of matrix $R$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column, then $R_{ji}$ would mean the entry in the $j$th row, $i$th column. It's the position of the letter, and not the letter itself, that tells you row vs column.

Now if I were writing a book would I use the notation $R_{ij}$ (with two indices) to mean the $(i,j)$th entry of $R$ and also $R_i$ (with one index) to mean the $i$th row? Probably not, as it seems bound to cause confusion. Is it possible the book you're reading did exactly this? Yes. (Though in the chapter you linked, I only see $R_i$ and not $R_{ij}$.)

Comment: the book refers to it as aij for entries, not Rij, but I was confused by what R meant. so what I take from this is that in the format aij, rij or whatever, the first letter is the matrix, and the second letter is always the row, and the third always the column. so we can have Rb and Rc for example, and b and c will always refer to the whole row of b and the whole row of c?

Comment: @AaronR I would discourage setting up a really rigid framework of notation for yourself. Use context, it helps.

Comment: that is a good idea, but in this context Ri and Rj are row i and row j correct? as in for example R2 --> R3 would be interchanging row 2 and row 3

Comment: @AaronR Yes, that's correct (within this context). But this row-focused notation is context-specific.